# ALAssets groups enumeration: how to check for completion?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

ALAssets use a separated thread to manage enumeration, i have to know when enumeration terminate.

The block prototype for group enumeration is :

`typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock)(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)`;

How can i add a completion block ?

Comment: At this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html i found "Preparing an assets for use" that speak about VAsynchronousKeyValueLoading and use block to check completion... but i'm not sure that is the right direction...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution that is documented only in part.

When group enumeration is terminated, ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock is invoked with group=nil. So you can write something like:

```
void (^groupsEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *,BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){ 
    if (group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetsEnumerator];

    }else {
        NSLog(@"group enumeration terminated");
    }
};
```

The same solution is valid for assets enumeration (this is not documented -.- )

```
 void (^assetsEnumerator)(ALAsset *,NSUInteger,BOOL*) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){    
    if (result !=nil) {
       //do something with result asset

    }else {
        NSLog(@"Assets enumeration terminated");
    }
};
```

Comment: what do you do when it never sends a nil asset.

Comment: sorry dear but i got asset nil when there is no images in album!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

        if (result == nil) {
            return;
        }

        if (index + 1 == group.numberOfAssets) {
        //Do what you want. Im using delegate to notify my parent class about finish.
            [delegate didGroupEnumerated:group];
        }

    }];
```